# How do I import Svelte components in SvelteKit project without TypeScript errors?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I want to import a Svelte component from `component/button.svelte`. But I keep getting this error:

```sh
   component/button.svelte' is not a module
```

Following the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761623/how-do-you-import-a-svelte-component-in-a-typescript-file) doesn't help either.

Comment: `import Button from './button.svelte';` 
did you import it this way?

Comment: @ShrijiKondan I did

Comment: That should work, you can import svelte files into .svelte files do you happen to have a codesandbox sample?