# Is there a way to use svelte getContext etc. svelte functions in Typescript files?

Tags: typescript, svelte

I am using getContext with [svelte-simple-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-simple-modal) for modals in my project.

Is there a way to use getContext etc. in Typescript files?
I am getting a `500: Function called outside component initialization` when calling svelte functions in Typescript files.

I have tried the methods mentioned in [how-do-you-import-a-svelte-component-in-a-typescript-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761623/how-do-you-import-a-svelte-component-in-a-typescript-file).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you share some code with what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `getContext` inside TypeScript files, but you can only call it during initialization of the component - that is, the first time the contents of the component's script tag are run.

```
// TS code
import { getContext } from 'svelte';

export function getFooContext() {
  const foo = getContext('foo');
}

export function fails() {
  setTimeout(() => getFooContext(), 100);
}

// Svelte code
<script>
  import { getFooContext } from './somewhere';
  
  // this is ok
  getFooContext();
  // this fails because it's called after the component is initialized
  setTimeout(() => getFooContext(), 100);
  // this fails because the function has a setTimout which is resolved
  // after the component is initialized
  fails();
</script>
```

You cannot call `getContext` or `setContext` or any of Svelte's lifecycle functions outside of the component initialization, which means you can't call it

- asynchronously (for example after a timeout)
- in reaction to a DOM event of the component
- etc